# How to delete a string which starts and ends with specific characters in Terminal?

Tags: regex, terminal, character-encoding

I have a file that contains something like this

```
<reportElement key="image-2" mode="Opaque" rr="a137f368-9d34-46be-adf8-2c0930a07e16"/>  
<reportElement key="line-109" backcolor="#FFFFFF" rr="ec29975c-9bc6-4250-9124-a18a599dd5ab"/>
```

How can I delete, with terminal, these whole strings

```
rr="***"
```

whatever numbers they cointain?

I mean, I need to have a copy of this file without the *rr* field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

> sed -e 's/(rr\=\".*\")//g'